# How to avoid race conditions from concurrent users querying & decrementing a DB to see if an item is "in-stock" before purchasing goods?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement a simple marketplace where users can buy and sell items to each other.

Implementing the basic Database Schema is not too difficult...

However, I am having some difficulties with figuring out how I can validate whether a seller can actually fulfill an order with their available stock. I have developed the following idea, but I think it is problematic, and there may be a better way.

- Perform a basic sanity check when the user decides to "Check-Out"
  their cart

  Query all items in the DB and ensure that all items in the basket are still in stock. If this fails, notify the customer that he must remove flagged items from the cart before continuing.
- Collect payment information using the Stripe API to create a customer instance. This represents a full, good-faith effort to purchase goods. A charge is created and waits for validation before being authorized.
- Final validation: Each item in the Database is queried, and its "in-stock" counter is decremented by the amount purchased by the customer.

  If there is not enough stock to satisfy an order, the transaction is aborted and the Charge is not captured

  I will need to implement a way to create a "Database Rollback" in case something goes wrong. I can avoid the need for a premature rollback by querying all items and ensuring that each one has enough stock before beginning the decrements, but I will still need a rollback for multiple users.
- If validation succeeds, authorize the Charge, knowing that the seller will not be required to request a charge-back due to insufficient stock.

Now, here is a situation where my method will absolutely fail:

Jim and Robert both decide on the same T-Shirt, only one in stock. Jim has a cart of 100 items (the T-Shirt is at the very bottom), and enters his payment information before Robert. The application gets the first OK from the API, and begins to go down the line through the items that he ordered, bringing their listed stock down. When item #70 in Jim's cart is still being processed by the validation method, Robert finally enters his card information. His order is validated, he is able to decrement the stock of the T-Shirt before Jim, and his Charge is captured, creating an official Purchase Order/Receipt.

Robert's transaction will now be aborted, and the DB will need to roll-back 99 items. This requires a lot of logic and error handling, and will probably still be fairly error prone if something goes wrong with the Database logic.

I could also simply charge for the 99 items and notify him that the T-Shirt could not be purchased at that time.

I'm using MongoDB/Mongoose right now. I'm not sure how to do rollbacks - my first idea would be to push each "update" query into a "history" array, and if a failure condition is met, use `.map()` on that history array to do an inverted set of updates which essentially return all items to their original condition.

Alternatively, I could try to implement a queue system - write some Express middleware for Mongoose that ensures that the "Decrement stock from DB" operation is handled synchronously, but this sort of puts transactions into a state of Limbo, and I don't like the idea of making a customer wait 10 minutes to see if their order went through. I also don't know how to implement a queue - create a plain JS method in the API? Create a new DB collection for "Queued Orders" have my API constantly checking that endpoint through a cron job to see if there are entries with "State: Decrement Pending", implement a synchronous for loop and use async await within for each Mongoose Update Query, before continuing to the next?

What do you guys think is the best way to handle this? Are there any gaps in my approach that I missed?

Answer (score 2):

I have had to solve a similar problem on a ticket shop for a film festival - this is what I did:

- Make sure your cart has a sane expiration interval (and your users know that)
- When calculating available stock of an item, subtract whatever is in any active cart from the total stock: This pushes the race from the checkout (where it is fatal) to where you fill the cart (where it is no problem)
- Immediately after putting something into the cart, check for out of stock and remove it from the cart again if necessary, showing the user a notice

This means, that the stock can become negative for a few milliseconds, but nobody can actually buy the item in this time, making it a theoretical-only problem.

In addition to that it creates a better picture of the real world: In a brick-and-morter shop, you "win" not by being the first to pay for an item , but by being the first to have it in your cart.

Comment: I see. This would imply that there is a method needed to clean out everyone's carts periodically. Also - What's to stop a griefer from filling his cart with as many items as possible to lock people out? This method is great for avoiding fatal errors which can lead to Payment disputes, but I am lukewarm towards creating a situation where sellers will have the exposure of their items minimized under any condition - I would like to somehow discourage hoarding and slowpoke behavior which locks users out of purchasing and hurting the sellers

Comment: That's typically how a programmer will think, the stakeholders in the business won't share the same view at least in my experience, adding to cart doesn't imply a commitment to buy so decrementing for stock (even for typical session of 20 minutes) is not a sane business idea. With persistent carts a item may come back into stock again by the time a user purchases which could be days or weeks later (after receiving reminders).

Comment: @Mikhail Cleaning out the carts is a very low cost operation, that can be routinely run e.g. before putting an item into the cart

Comment: @MâttFrëëman I beg to differ: The stakeholders will be very eager to avoid an order they can't fulfill (at least here in Europe, where the balance of power between vendor and consumer is very different). And 20 minutes is not what I ment with "sane"

Comment: @EugenRieck I had the "lock items for 20 minutes" in my previous implementation and it's proven to be quite problematic as a lot of users simply don't understand that inventories was locked for them and when they try to buy again on different session, the item was marked as sold. It's a safe and lazy way to do merchandise. IMO, the best way is to lock the inventory ONLY when a payment is received, and fail any concurrent payment process if item has been sold.

Comment: @LionelChan Whether or not it is lazy is up to discussion but it is safe. Here in Europe exists something called "consumer protection", and it is quite clear: If you put something into your shopping cart in a webshop and behave reasonably (i.e. don't time out), you are entitled to buy this item at this price. If the merchant doesn't deliver, he is wide open to legal trouble.

Comment: @Eugen Rieck I see. Whether locking before or after payment is really up to the business itself to decide. I have seen, like for example, Amazon, keep your item in the cart as long as the item is still available (no time limit), and tells you "your item has been removed" when the item has sold out. Other examples such as buying a concert ticket, does give you a time limit when locking the inventory for you.